# How to check TabNavigator Page efficiently

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I am using flex TabNavigator to display few datagrids. Each datagrid have same structure but populated with different dataProvider. Currently I am using following method to check which datagrid or an element from a tab was clicked.

if(TabNavigator.selectedIndex == 0){

}else if(TabNavigator.selectedIndex == 1){

}
...
else if(TabNavigator.selectedIndex == 4){

}

My question is is there an efficient way to check this? Is there anyway I can organize similar structure in to one property?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all your data providers into an array in the same sequence as the items in the tab navigator. Then simply do:

```
dataGrid.dataProvider = dataProviderArray[tabNavigator.selectedIndex];
```

Here 'dataProviderArray' is the array of all the data providers for the data grid.
Also, since you mentioned that the data grid has the same structure for all the tabs, I am assuming you are using one Data Grid and not multiple. If not, I would recommend you keep one data grid only and change its data provider when the tabs change.

Hope this solves your question.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it gives few inaccuracies. Sometimes the index values get swapped, eg. The data for 2nd index gets loaded in 3rd Index.

Comment: As long as you are not manipulating your sources array, this should not happen. Check your code, or post it in your question if you want me to have a look at it. Thanks.